# Why I get Comunication Error(1001) when i deploy my apllication web in Google Cloud?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, restlet

When I try to connect with the Wikipedia api for search informacion about an author in localHost, everything goes perfect, but when I try to deploy the application in Google Cloud, I get a search error: "Communication Error (1001) - The connector failed to complete the communication with the server)".

I think that maybe the error is because when i try to do the search in localhost, the protocol is HTTP, but when I deploy the application the protocol of the search is HTTPS

```
package aiss.model.resource;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.restlet.resource.ClientResource;
import org.restlet.resource.ResourceException;

import aiss.model.wikipedia.Query;
import aiss.model.wikipedia.Result;

public class WikipediaResource {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(WikipediaResource.class.getName());

    private final String baseURL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&utf8=1&srsearch=";

    public Query getSearch(String query) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String autor = URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
        String uri = baseURL + autor;

        log.log(Level.FINE, "URI:" + uri);
        ClientResource cr = null;
        Result search = null;
        try {
             cr = new ClientResource(uri);
            search = cr.get(Result.class);
            log.warning("SUCCESS: " + cr.getResponse().getStatus());
            return search.getQuery();
        } catch (ResourceException e) {
            log.warning("Search error in Wikipedia api: " + cr.getResponse().getStatus());
            log.warning(uri);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't now what i have to put to fix that error, maybe I have to give to the server another one header?

Thank you for the attention